# Creation of a DropWizard micro-service for running reports.

Tags: java, mysql, maven, dropwizard

I have a good project where we are currently generating reports with jasper reports files .
Suddenly I am to generate these reports by the use of "Creation of a DropWizard micro-service for running reports. "

I have no idea what to do or where to start with or whats my goal . I looked into the web a bit just to confused myself.

Can anyone help me with the understanding what is to be done here and what will be the starting point.

Your guidelines will highly be appriciated

Comment: You should possibly figure out what your goal is first. As far as DropWizard is concerned it doesn't get more straight forward than the [Getting Started guide](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html). Most likely create REST resources that produce Jasper reports based on their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the microservice architectural style is an approach to developing a single application as a suite of small services, each running in its own process and communicating with lightweight mechanisms, often an HTTP resource API. - As described in Martin Fowler's blog http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html.

The idea in short is to create small services that have very little responsibility on what needs to be done and it can further interact with host of other microservices to achieve the end result. This brings a lot of agility in terms of replacing a small part of your functionality to something else without having to redeploy the entire ecosystem.

By the looks of it, you should possibly consider figuring out how small each of your services to be and what kind of responsibilities that they hold. Hope this helps.